# Skip password or pattern screen and directly open app

Tags: android

I'm trying to skip lock screen when i make call from my own Call app. When the user locks the phone for the first time it will turn off the screen by default. Then if the user presses the unlock the phone it should not go to password or pattern screen.

I've searched using several keywords. But not able to find out a solution yet. It would be great if anyone could answer or point out to the required posts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be able to bypass the security i.e. `passwords` or `biometric` or `pattern screen` then there is no meaning of having password feature on devices.

**It is not possible and also you should not do it.**

Comment: It is not a security breach. This feature is present in all call applications in Android. The lock screen will be shown when the call completes.